# How to empty the element in the object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have an object like this:

```
var measure = {
    "name":{"id":1},
    "name2":{"id2":2},
    "name3":{"id3":3}
};
```

How to empty the elements in the object on the button click.

http://jsfiddle.net/5bdugpt6/

the expected result is `measure = {};`

Thanks for the help

Comment: Looks  like the expected result is the answer to your question, if you want to overwrite the `measure` var.

Comment: Just put `measure = {}` in the function.

Comment: Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/5bdugpt6/1/

Comment: Thanks Barmar and PeterKA. Working fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are three ways :

1. **Delete properties "manually"**

```js
delete measure.name;
delete measure.name2;
delete measure.name3;
```

2. **Delete properties in a for-in loop**

```js
for(prop in measure) {
    delete measure[prop];
}
```

3. **Replace the object with a fresh object**

```js
measure = {};
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5bdugpt6/2/)**

Comment: Avoid `delete` if possible.  Because of how javascript works, you will very likely remove the javascript engine's ability to optimize access to `measure` -- it will become a slow object.  It can even be beneficial to copy an object rather than delete fields.  Your third solution is the much preferred way.

Comment: @MichaelHays, there may well be optimisation issues in the latest JS engines (and I guess we are talking about Chrome here) but is it not also still true that `delete` gives garbage collection a direct instruction, and it therefore good for memory management. I would have thought that trumped some "slow object" consideration in most cases.

Comment: It's more about how deletion works in an open addressed hash map, and not specifically anything related to javascript.  There is necessarily a lingering deleted object that must be skipped over when doing subsequent searches for objects.  These accumulate over time, create collisions, and waste memory.  Honestly, it's not something one would really notice unless this is a long-running application with deletes happening all the time, but I thought it would be a benefit to the OP to at least recognize it.